# RSS to SQL Database

Tags: python, sql, rss

I want to take the rss feed from http://www.reddit.com/new/.rss?sort=new and put it in a SQL table.

I was able to get the RSS feed into python (code below)

I just don't know how to go from here to importing this into a SQL database?

I'm working on a jupyter notebook and just need some help getting this project off the ground. I also want to make sure everything is DISTINCT and not duplicated.

````py
    import feedparser

    a_reddit_rss_url = 'http://www.reddit.com/new/.rss?sort=new'

    feed = feedparser.parse( a_reddit_rss_url )

    if (feed['bozo'] == 1):
        print("Error Reading/Parsing Feed XML Data")    
    else:
        for item in feed[ "items" ]:
            print(item) ```

``` python

    import feedparser
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from bs4.element import Comment


    def tag_visible(element):
        if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
            return False
        if isinstance(element, Comment):
            return False
        return True

    def text_from_html(body):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
        texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
        visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
        return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

    # Define URL of the RSS Feed I want
    a_reddit_rss_url = 'http://www.reddit.com/new/.rss?sort=new'

    feed = feedparser.parse( a_reddit_rss_url )

    if (feed['bozo'] == 1):
        print("Error Reading/Parsing Feed XML Data")    
    else:
        for item in feed[ "items" ]:
            dttm = item[ "date" ]
            title = item[ "title" ]
            summary_text = text_from_html(item[ "summary" ])
            link = item[ "link" ]


            print("====================")
            print("Title: {} ({})\nTimestamp: {}".format(title,link,dttm))
            print("--------------------\nSummary:\n{}".format(summary_text))
````

SQL table/database with the date, title, summary, and link all having their own column.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one responded to your post, I'll take a crack at it.  To do an insert into SQL Server from a Pandas DF, try the following:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# create timer
start_time = time.time()
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


# df = this_is_your_pandas_dataframe
# this sample code assumes 4 fields: [Name],[Address],[Age],[Work]
# obviously, change this to suit your specific needs

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
    r'SERVER=Name_Of_Server;'
    r'DATABASE=Name_Of_Database;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1([Name],[Address],[Age],[Work]) values (?,?,?,?)', 
                    row['Name'], 
                    row['Address'], 
                    row['Age'],
                    row['Work'])
    cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()

# see total time to do insert
print("%s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```